# Почему может не загружаться внешний скрипт?

Tags: html

Проблема касается воспроизведения ошибки, присланной пользователем.
Есть сайт, который использует Quaderno Checkout для оплаты.

```
<head>
  <script src="https://checkout.quaderno.io/checkout.js"></script>
</head>
```

Какие могут быть причины, чтобы скрипт не загрузился?

Мне удалось найти только ситуацию, когда соединение перестало быть безопасным. Например, из-за неверно установленной даты на компьютере. 
Текущий SSL-сертификат действует до DD.MM.2019. Таким образом, если у пользователя дата съехала, то скрипт не загрузится. Что еще?

Comment: Как вариант, можно запросить у пользователя скриншот консоли браузера, тогда возможно станет яснее. Потому что проблема может быть не в загрузке, а в выполнении файла (например, старый IE не поддерживает какой-то новый метод)

Comment: В данном случае известно, что у пользователя Хром.

Comment: Хотелось бы добавить проверку `window.QuadernoCheckout` и если оно null, показывать пользователю какое-то осмысленное сообщение.

Comment: Причин может быть куча, вирус в браузере пользователя, который блокирует загрузку JS файлов, или как часто бывает, у пользователя в браузере установлено расширение (ADBlock или что то в этом роде) и расширение может блокировать JS. Пусть пользователь попробует через другой браузер.

Comment: @Arsen спасибо за наводку. Действительно adBlock стоит проверить.